# Converting 'senses' and 'rhs' from CPLEX to CVXPY

Tags: cplex, cvxpy

I'm trying to convert some code from pure CPLEX to CVXPY with the CPLEX solver. The original code goes like this:

```
    p = cplex.Cplex()
    p.objective.set_sense(p.objective.sense.maximize)

    obj = np.zeros(numCols)

    for i in range(numSamples):
        if labels[i] == 0:
            for b in range(numBuckets):
                obj[zv_ + b*numSamples + i] = C
        else:
            for b in range(numBuckets):
                obj[zv_ + numBuckets*numSamples + b*numSamples + i] = 1


    p.linear_constraints.add(rhs=rhs,senses=senses)
    p.linear_constraints.set_names(zip(range(constraint_cnt),cnames))


    lb = np.zeros(numCols)
    ub = np.ones(numCols)
    p.variables.add(obj = obj, lb = lb, ub = ub, columns=cols, types=types, names=names)

    p.parameters.timelimit.set(maxtime)
    p.solve()
    sol = p.solution
```

This is my attempt at converting it to CVXPY syntax:

```
    import cvxpy as cp
    obj = np.zeros(numCols)

    for i in range(numSamples):
        if labels[i] == 0:
            for b in range(numBuckets):
                obj[zv_ + b*numSamples + i] = C
        else:
            for b in range(numBuckets):
                obj[zv_ + numBuckets*numSamples + b*numSamples + i] = 1

    objective = cp.Maximize(sum(obj))
```

What I'm very confused by is the way CPLEX specifies 'rhs', as well as 'senses'. What are these supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CPLEX Python API documentation for [Cplex.linear_constraints.add](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.LinearConstraintInterface-class.html#add) says:

> senses must be either a list of single-character strings or a string
>   containing the senses of the linear constraints. Each entry must be
>   one of 'G', 'L', 'E', and 'R', indicating greater-than, less-than,
>   equality, and ranged constraints, respectively.
>
> rhs is a list of floats, specifying the righthand side of each linear
>   constraint.

CVXPY is a modeling language, so rather than specifying the sense as 'G', 'L', 'E', you would use `>=`, `<=`, and `==` (i.e., Python comparison operators). The righthand side of the constraints, will be a number for an individual constraint (e.g., a Python `float` or `int`), or perhaps a numpy array for a group of constraints.

The CVXPY [examples](https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/index.html) should give you a good idea of how do things.